# Spark Submit fails with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I am using spark 1.3.1 prebuild version spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getSystemProperties(Utils.scala:1418)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.(SparkConf.scala:58)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkConf.(SparkConf.scala:52)     at
>   com.zoho.zbi.Testing.test(Testing.java:43)    at
>   com.zoho.zbi.Testing.main(Testing.java:39) Using Spark's default log4j
>   profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties

I am trying a simple demo app to save to cassandra

```
SparkConf batchConf= new SparkConf()
            .setSparkHome(sparkHome)
            .setJars(jars)
            .setAppName(ZohoBIConstants.getAppName("cassandra"))//NO I18N
            .setMaster(master).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");

            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(batchConf);
            // here we are going to save some data to Cassandra...
            List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
                    Person.newInstance(1, "John", new Date()),
                    Person.newInstance(2, "Anna", new Date()),
                    Person.newInstance(3, "Andrew", new Date())
            );
//          Person test = Person.newInstance(1, "vini", new Date())''
            System.out.println("Inside Java API Demo : "+people);
            JavaRDD<Person> rdd = sc.parallelize(people);
            System.out.println("Inside Java API Demo rdd : "+rdd);
            javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("test", "people", mapToRow(Person.class)).saveToCassandra();
            System.out.println("Stopping sc");
            sc.stop();
```

when i submit using spark submit its working

```
bin/spark-submit --class "abc.efg.Testing" --master spark://xyz:7077 /home/test/target/uber-Cassandra-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is my pom

dependencies

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Scala -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END Scala -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- Cassandra Spark Connector dependency -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
<!-- Cassandra java Connector dependency -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
  </dependency> 

<!-- Spark Core dependency -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

and i build using

```
<build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <finalName>uber-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </build>
```

but when i submit through code its not working, any help is much appriciated.. I tried added scala2.10.4 prop in pom still no luck

I am running in eclipse as run as application with all master,spark home and jars set to sparkConf the error shows exactly in sparkConf

My scala version is

scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

is this has anything to do with the issue?

How to swtich to an older version of scala? In the doc it says spark1.3.1 supports scala 2.10.x versions, please let me know how to fix this

Comment: Did you find a solution so far? I've a similar problem and would be interested in an answer, too.

Comment: Did you try the answer from @Maksud ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the incompatibilities in Scala versions. Prebuild Spark 1.3.1 distribution is compiled with older Scala 2.10 because some of the Spark dependencies are not supported under 2.11, including JDBC support.

I would suggest to run your Spark cluster with Scala 2.10. However, if you want you can also compile your Spark package with Scala 2.11 in the following way:

```
dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

Comment: @mithra (the OP)  This seems like a good answer.  Did you try it?

Comment: Apparently, it's also written in the Spark documentation page, in the Downloading section ( I missed it ... and this answer helped me :P): Spark runs on Java 7+, Python 2.6+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 1.5.1 uses Scala 2.10. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.10.x).

Comment: Yes, I got the same issue. This answer resolved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i was experiencing same issue in scala IDE.and below steps resolved that.

Note:-check compatibility as per your scala-spark. for me it is scala version - 2.11.* is compatible with spark 2.4.*

Go the project >> right click >> properties >> scala compiler >> select "use project settings" option >>  and change "scala installation" >> apply >> apply and close..... good to go.

[click on below image link to see setting of Scala IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi1MX.png)