# Spark 1.6 dependencies cross compiled with scala 2.11.0

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I am looking for maven dependency details for Spark 1.6.

Here are the maven dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have selected the following under project->properties->scala compiler in eclipse Luna IDE. 
[image]

However, I see errors like the following
spark-core_2.11-1.6.0.jar of hworkspace build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.11.0). In case this report is mistaken, this check can be disabled in the compiler preference page.

I have followed all steps given here -> [spark build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.10.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507966/spark-build-path-is-cross-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-scala-2-10-0)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using scala 2.10.6 so you need to use `spark-core_2.10` and not <s>`spark-core_2.11`</s>.

It is same code, compiled with different versions of scala.

Comment: Hi Jean, Thanks. I want to use Spark 1.6 which seems to be using spark-core_2.11. What scala compiler version must I use for this artifact?

Answer (score 0):

Spark 1.6, 2.11 artifacts are compiled with Scala 2.11.8. This has solved the dependency issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this, and also in eclipse build path, use 2.11 version..

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.spark-scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-scala</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>Spark in Scala</description>
    <inceptionYear>2010</inceptionYear>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
        <!-- Put the Scala version of the cluster -->
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- repository to add org.apache.spark -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- "package" command plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```